# Rewrite subdomain to main domain for images only using htaccess

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have a domain, where everything except image\css etc. are handled by a single php file. However after a reorganisation, alot of images have been moved from sub-domains to the main domain. So I'm looking for a way to redirect all image\css files to the main domain if they were originally on one of the sub-domains. My current code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.ico|\.bmp|\.css|\.ts|\.js)$
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ /index.php [L]
```

I've tried a couple of ways to redirect it, but I seem to break on of the existing rules, whatever I try.

Thanks

The final solution I came up with

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check the request isn't for the main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$
# Check the request is for a static resource
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|ico|bmp|css|ts|js)$
# Redirect to main domain
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain\.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# if the request isn't for index.php,
# (invisibly) redirect to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.ico|\.bmp|\.css|\.ts|\.js)$
RewriteRule !^index\.php$ /index.php [L]
```

For information only. As really the credit goes to jon for the answer I just tweaked it for my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URLs in your HTML still point to the subdomains, you'll need to setup htaccess redirects on those subdomains, not on the main domain, as the requests will still be going to the subdomains.

For example in `/var/www/vhosts/sub.domain.com/httpdocs/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|ico|bmp|css|ts|js)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And in `/var/www/vhosts/sub2.domain.com/httpdocs/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|ico|bmp|css|ts|js)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment that Apache handles each subdomain as if it were the main one, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check the request isn't for the main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(www\.)?domain\.com$
# Check the request is for a static resource
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|ico|bmp|css|ts|js)$
# Redirect to main domain
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, that would have worked but I missed one crucial detail (sorry my fault) I have setup apache so that it handle all subdomains as if they were the main domain. So in the short term the images are still working, but in the long term I want to redirect them, so that search engines etc. stop looking for the subdomain.

Comment: Just done a check and images aren't been redirected correct. I've replaced both references to domain.com with the correct domain, then pasted it in above my exsiting code. (So that the pages still redirect to the index.php), I've also left the \ in the first domain.com wasn't sure if it was part of the regex or not. Just to clarify I'm wanting jon.blog.com\fred\test.jpg to redirect to blog.com\fred\test.jpg

Comment: Think I've sorted it, I don't use www, I use just the domain\subdomain. I made some tweaks around that and end up with the code I've added to the question, but I'm going to mark your answer as accepted cos I wouldn't have got there without your answer, I only tweaked about 5 charcters :-)