# htaccess redirect for load a specific image url at subdomain from main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-alias

I have a subdomain (us.example.com) and main domain (example.com). I want to redirect my subdomain url to main domain only for a specific image. For example if I hit `http://us.example.com/images/test.jpg` then it should redirect to `http://example.com/images/test.jpg`

I am trying 301 redirect as below but it's not working.

```
Redirect 301 https://us.example.com/images/test.jpg  https://example.com/images/test.jpg
```

I have tried other rules also but they all work on complete image directory not for a specific image under directory.

**Update** 
Changed rule like this -

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^us\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?images/test.jpg$ https://example.com/images/test.jpg [R=301,L]`

But no luck.

Comment: Please paste your .htaccess file else take a look on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677792/rewrite-subdomain-to-main-domain-for-images-only-using-htaccess

Comment: Thanks @Kate I don't think complete .htaccess file require here. I have already pasted rule I have applied. For your link I already referred this but it works on complete directory and I want to set rule for single image only.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Redirect` directive](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_alias#redirect) from **`mod_alias`** has the following syntax:

```
Redirect [status] [URL-path] URL
```

and, as you see, it receives/accepts the URL path, and not the whole URI/URL for matching.

For the subdomain match, use an `<if>` directive:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'us.example.com'">
    RedirectPermanent /imges/test.jpg https://example.com/images/test.jpg
</If>
```

The same can be achieved using **`mod_rewrite`** as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^us\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?images/test.jpg$ https://example.com/images/test.jpg [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi @hjpotter, Tried all but not working. check updated question.

Comment: @HelloPython Not working how? Do you have any other rules? The rules above should appear at the very beginning of your htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this mate ,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^us.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

What will happen for the above .htaccess was ,

If you visit

> us.domain.com/somelink

It will redirect to

> domain.com/somelink

***EDIT :***

Suppose if the above doesn't help try the one below with symlinks

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^us.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

***Update 1 :***

For only test.jpg

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^us.domain.com/images/test.jpg [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/images/test.jpg [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks!! But I want it for a single image url only not all urls I want to redirect.

Comment: @HelloPython you want it for only test.jpg or all jpg ?

Comment: @HelloPython check the update made above and update me whether it works or not mate.